# Матрица java

Tags: java

Как написать условие проверки,если данная матрица является треугольной? ниже то,до чего я дошла. работает только для первых двух рядов..но если что-то меняю в последнем - не работает.(все равно выдает правильный результат - что матрица треугольная)

```
 public static int matr(int[][]pole){
     int a=0;
     int k=1;
     for(int j = 0; j < pole.length; j++) {
         for(int i = 0; i < pole[0].length - k; i++) {
             if (pole[j][i] == 0) {
                 a = 3;
             } else {
                 a = 0;   
             }
         }

         if(a == 0) {
             break;
         }
         k++;
     }
     return a;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно помню что такое треугольная матрица то вот

```
public class Matrix {

    int[][] array = {
        {1, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 0, 0},
        {1, 4, 3, 0},
        {1, 4, 4, 4}
    };

    boolean check(){
        return  checkFromLeft() || checkFromRight();
    }

    boolean checkFromLeft(){

        for(int y = array.length-1; y >= 0; y--){
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++){
                if (array[y][x] != 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean checkFromRight() {
        for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
            for (int x = array.length - 1; x > y; x--) {
                if (array[y][x] != 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Matrix().check()?"Треугольная! :)":"нет, не треугольная :(");
    }
}
```

Comment: @wwvv мне кажется, в строке

     return  checkFromLeft() || checkFromRight();

следует заменить операцию

     return  checkFromLeft() ^ checkFromRight();

Иначе в треугольные попадут диагональные матрицы и нулевые.

Comment: Если диагональная матрица не является треугольной, то Вы правы. Сорри подзабыл уже немного.